# Chef Cookbook: filter a list of files to delete

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have a variable storing the files which should be keep

```
default['keep']['files'] = ['a.txt', 'b.txt']
```

And bellow files exist on the server

```
'a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt', 'd.txt'
```

I want to delete those file which is not in default['keep']['files'], i.e. c.txt and d.txt
but I am not able to figure out how to get the list of the files to be deleted.

```
// How should I get the list so that i can loop it?
???.each do |file_name|
  directory "Delete #{file_name}" do
    path my_folder_path
    recursive true
    action :delete
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just subtract keep array from the file list array which will leave you with an array of file names to delete.
e.g.

```
a1 = ['file1', 'file2']
a2 = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4']
a3 = a2 - a1 #results in a3 => ['file3', 'file4']
```

So you could do something like

```
files_to_keep = ['a.txt', 'b.txt']
all_files = Dir.entries
files_to_delete = all_files - files_to_keep
files_to_delete.each do |file_name|
  if ! Dir.exist? #Check that the file name is not an actual directory
    # write your code to delete the file named file_name
  end
end
```

But you might want to sort the arrays first, code is untested but should be fine